# JNLP use both classes and jars

Tags: java, jar, classpath, jnlp

Can I use both signed jars and plain classes in my JNLP application?
I have a remote codebase, say `http://xxx:777/yyy`, which is an IIS published directory. I can place my jars there and plug them in with `<resources>` tag. 
But plain classes can't be found.
I can create a URLClassloader, but it works like a fork: classes from it can't see jars and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Just added links to jars for my URLClassloader.